# Spherical Grid Identifcation

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis, manifolds, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to see how the lower half of [these](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroederNumber.html) grids look like when I make the following identification onto the unit sphere:

[CLICK HERE TO SEE IMAGE](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7439/9371865421_6530c0388d_b.jpg)

In notation, how would one represent this "identification," namely the edges so that there exists an equivalence relation so that it is equivalent to a sphere, and what would the grid [look like](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29249/spherical-identification-of-the-half-lattice-of-an-n2-grid#29249) on the sphere under this proposed identification?

$\dagger$ Complex analysis may provide some good insight into grid structure on the sphere.

Comment: I mean, what identification would have to be made for this to happen?

Comment: [Look at this.](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/M132Fall07_QuotientSpaces.pdf)

Comment: The image is unavailable.